# Regex.IsMatch hangs, apparently its looking for infinite matches and never returns

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking to validate user input using regex below. User is allowed to enter positive integer values separated by comma(,) or space. The problem is when during negative testing, I enter a special character like ? or period(.),IsMatch hangs. Any help is appreciated.

```
new Regex("^\\s*[0-9]+\\s*(,*\\s*[0-9]+\\s*)*$")
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'hangs'?

Comment: `(,*\\s*[0-9]+\\s*)*` contains multiple optional patterns while only `[0-9]+` is obligatory, so it is a classical `(a+)+` like pattern causing catastrophic backtracking with non-matching strings. Please make sure there is at least 1 more obligatory pattern inside the quantified group. What are the pattern requirements? *User is allowed to enter positive integer values separated by comma(,) or space* does not explain why you have both comma and spaces optional in your pattern.

Comment: No repro. If I whack that into a toy project and call `abc.IsMatch("?")` it returns `false`.(`abc` is what I assigned the result of the `new` expression to)

Comment: Ok, try `@"^\s*[0-9]+(?:(?:\s*,\s*|\s+)[0-9]+)*\s*$"`

Answer (score 0):

The `(,*\\s*[0-9]+\\s*)*` pattern inside the regular expression contains multiple optional patterns while only `[0-9]+` is obligatory, so it is a classic `(a+)+` like pattern causing [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) with non-matching strings.

You should make sure there is at least 1 more obligatory pattern inside the quantified group, e.g.

```
@"^\s*[0-9]+(?:(?:\s*,\s*|\s+)[0-9]+)*\s*$"
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\s*` - optional 0+ leading whitespaces
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:(?:\s*,\s*|\s+)[0-9]+)*` - 0+ repetitions of:

  - `(?:\s*,\s*|\s+)` - either `,` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces or just 1+ whitespaces
  - `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `\s*` - optional 0+ trailing whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.